# What does '%8.1fC\n' mean?

Tags: string, matlab

I wanted to know the purpose of a percent inside a string with 8.1. Your help will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: 1. What language?  2. What context?  3. Look up `format specifiers`.

Comment: I know \n means spacing but that's about it.

Comment: `\n` doesn't mean "spacing".  It's a new line character.

Comment: @nhgrif this is C I believe since it is matlab

Comment: @nhgrif This is for returning the answer of an input so it'd be something like....`fprintf('The windchill is %8.1fF\n',WC2);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%8.1f` is a `format specifier`.  This should point you in the right direction for figuring out what all the parts mean.  It specifies the format in which a variable will be printed.  In this specific case, it is a place-holder for a floating point variable.  It reserves a width of at least 8 characters and a precision of 1.

For more information, do some research on `format specifiers`.  It's an extremely well documented and widely available topic for virtually every programming language.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, now I understand what I was reading. Sure will, thanks again!

Comment: Good answer to a bad question.